# How is the solution to arcsin($-1/2$) equal to (7/6)$\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve for the x-coordinate of the point 'A' which intersects with the x-axis in this equation:

$y= 4\sin^2x$ + $8\sin x$ + $3$

Image of the question (it's from an A-Level exam):

[image]

My working is as follows, I factorized the equation and obtained the result $\sin x = $(-1/2)

Through a calculator I obtained the result: ($-\pi/6)$. Adding $2\pi$ for a positive result gives (11/6)$\pi$

However, solving manually by quadrants I obtain: $\pi+\arcsin(1/2) = (7/6)$$\pi$. Which is the answer in the mark scheme.

I am unsure which is the right answer for 'A'. Using a graphing calculator, I can see that both are roots for the equation however without the graphic calculator I can't tell which is the right answer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Both solve the equation, but $\dfrac76\pi$ is the least positive solution

Comment: $7\pi/6<11\pi/6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find that $\sin x=a$, for some $a\in[-1,1]$, you don't necessarily have
$$
x=\arcsin a
$$
unless you know that $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (this interval is the range of the arcsine function). Rather, you can deduce that either
$$
x=\arcsin a+2k\pi
$$
or
$$
x=\pi-\arcsin a+2k\pi
$$
where $k$ denotes any integer. The two possibilities collapse into one just for $a=\pm1$.

If you have other limitations, such as finding the least positive value of $x$ such that
$$
4\sin^2x+8\sin x+3=0
$$
then you can solve the quadratic equation $4t^2+8t+3=0$ that gives $t=-3/2$ or $t=-1/2$. The former solution must be discarded, so you remain with $\sin x=-1/2$ and therefore either
$$
x=-\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi
$$
or
$$
x=\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi
$$
because $\arcsin(-1/2)=-\pi/6$.

The least positive value from the first case is $11\pi/6$; from the second case it is $7\pi/6$, which is the value you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are solving for the smallest positive value of $x$ such that $y = 4\sin^2x + 8\sin x + 3 = 0$.

You correctly found that $\sin x = -1/2$.  The general solution to this equation is
$$x = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or
$$x = \pi - \left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
The smallest positive value of $x$ is $7\pi/6$.